# PhpStorm completion, type hint generic

Tags: generics, phpstorm, phpdoc, type-hinting

I would love to find a way (if that's even possible?) for PhpStorm to auto complete code generated by my `Factory` class without having to write a PHPDoc every time I pull a class from it.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
class Factory
{
    public function getManager(string $class)
    {
        // if in cache ... returns

        // not in cache > init
        $manager = new $class();
        $this->doStuff($manager);
        return $manager;
    }

    public function doStuff($manager) {}
}

$factory = new Factory();
/** @var DateTime $dtClass */
$dtClass = $factory->getManager(DateTime::class);
$dtClass->getTimestamp();
```

So in order to autocomplete & silence PhpStorm warnings I've to add that line after each `getManager()` calls with the corresponding class.

```
/** @var DateTime $dtClass */
```

I was wondering if a PHPDoc, a PhpStorm helper file or anything could help doing that?

```
    /**
     * @template T
     * @param string $class <T>
     * @return <T>
     */
    public function getManager(string $class)
    {
```

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata does exactly that. You can look at Laravel IDE helper (composer package; also has pre-generated files) that does that for Laravel and manually make such file for yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh My god ! thank you so much @LazyOne

I can't believe that only 10lines of code could save me so much time

So here is a quick round up.
Just create a **folder** `.phpstorm.meta.php` at the root of your project.
Inside create a `manager.meta.php`
Containing just:

```
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    override(
        \Factory::getManager(0),
        map([
            '' => '@',
        ])
    );
}
```

Et voilà !

Comment: Do not forget to accept your own answer: more noticeable in search results; easier to find working solution for other users.